# matrix that fails to be invertible using variables

Tags: matrices, inverse

> Find the values of $a$ which make this matrix not invertible
>
> \begin{pmatrix}
>         2 & a-3 & a^2 \\
>         2 & 1 & 4 \\
>         1 & a & 0 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}

Now I know that if the determinant is $0$ then it is not invertible, however when I attempt to solve for the determinant it yields $2a^3-a^2-4a-12$ and the roots of this equation are highly complex.

Comment: The determinant only has 1 real root, but it isn't an "easy" one. Is this an exercise you're supposed to be able to do "by hand", compute it manually? If so, perhaps you should (re)check, there's no typo?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the only real root as
$$
a = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{324} \left(\left(107862840 - 28343520 \sqrt{14}\right)^{1/3} + 54 \left(5 \left(137 + 36 \sqrt{14}\right)\right)^{1/3}\right)
\approx 2.4
$$

Comment: With regards to typos, if the $a^2$ in the upper-right corner is instead just $a$ then the singular values of $a$ are rational.

Answer (score 3):

Using the rule of [Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) it is easy to see that the determinant is zero if and only if $a$ is a real root of
$$
2a^3 - a^2 - 4a - 12=0.
$$
This gives $a=2.38875419925$. Perhaps somewhere there is a typo in this exercise. Indeed, if the upper right corner is $a$, and not $a^2$, then, using [semiclassical](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/137524/semiclassical) methods, $a$ is a root of
$$
(2a + 3)(a - 4)=0.$$